# Invalid graphql endpoint, Verify that 'layoutServiceHost' property in 'scjssconfig.json' file or appropriate environment variable is set

Tags: sxa, jss, sitecore-api, graphql, sxa-jss

I am a newbie here. I was editing the .env file for adding the graphQLEndpoints. But in between something broke and I got this error.

[image: This is the error I am getting in Front End side]

[image: This is the experience editor of Sitecore]

This is the `scjssconfig.json` file

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\rengokusc.dev.local",
    "apiKey": "ED741CD3-65AB-495F-9510-************",
    "deploySecret": "c2431oi1tk5a4k2cg5usr7jfxgtpqew396********",
    "deployUrl": "https://rengokusc.dev.local/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "https://rengokusc.dev.local/"
  }
}
```

I am using NextJS, Sitecore 10.3 (SXA with headless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Guys, I got the solution!!**
I am writing it down below:

After adding this `GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT=/sitecore/api/graph/edge` to the `.env` file, the error occurred.

**Cause:** I provided only path as the endpoint, you need to give the whole endpoint with site URL and path included. And if you check in `src/temp/config.js` you can see all the configurations for the project. 
*This was just some silly mistake, but learnt something new .*